# Issues with navigation between screens with expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

I am building a reac native expo application and i want to navigate to another page after successfully login. So i followed the documentation for expo and installed the following packages: @react-native-community/masked-view, @react-navigation/native, @react-navigation/native-stack, @react-navigation/stack, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-screens. Then i created a component to handle this navigation.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const RootStack = () => {
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='LoginScreen'>
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
}
export default RootStack;
```

And on my App.js file i put this:

```
import RootStack from './app/navigators/RootStack';

export default function App() {
  return <RootStack />;
}
```

When i run the expo app on the android device i see no errors or warnings, but app wont load.

[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, here's the text with improved grammar:

Please check your 'RootStack' component. It does not return anything.

You can either try this:

```
const RootStack = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='LoginScreen'>
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Or:

```
const RootStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='LoginScreen'>
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: You're right, thanks a lot, i forgot to add the return on that component.

Answer (score 1):

update your app.js code with the below code.

App.js file

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import RootStack from './app/navigators/RootStack';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(RootStack);
```

update your RootStack.js code with the below code.

```
const RootStack = () => ( 
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='LoginScreen'>
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

[expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/)

And yes check your entry point also, The entry point can be found in node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js In this, you can change your entry point. Initially, it is set to App, Look at the import statement where that component is coming from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help also, adding the "return" to the component fix the issue.

Comment: Double check my code if using this   = () => () syntax, no return needed

Comment: you can use parentheses to wrap implicitly returned JSX.